# query - group by max amount

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

tbl_transaction:

```
Sender       Receiver   Amount  Date
1102504637  31750690083 50      03/04/2013
1102504637  31750690083 50      04/04/2013
1102504637  31750690083 50      06/04/2013
1102504637  31750690083 50      07/04/2013
1102504637  31750690083 50      09/04/2013
1102504637  31750690083 50      10/04/2013
1102512397  31811645749 200     24/04/2013
1102512397  31811645749 200     01/04/2013
1102185152  31823355218 100     14/04/2013
1102185152  31823355218 100     22/04/2013
1102185152  31823355218 100     23/04/2013
```

I would like to get result based on sender who send up to 200 to the same receiver (based on earliest date / the first one send up to 200 will get to the result list).

I wanted to know how many people doing 50x4, 100x2, 200x1 transactions. So, only sender who send amount sum-up to 200 will be on the Result list. I am using SQL Server 2005.

Sample Result:

```
Sender          Receiver    Amount  count
1102504637  31750690083     50      4
1102512397  31811645749     200     1
1102185152  31823355218     100     2
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a cumulative sum for this.  The idea is then simple; just choose the rows where the cumulative sum is less than or equal to 200.

SQL Server 2005 does not have a built-in cumulative sum (SQL Server 2012 does).  I tend to use correlated subqueries in this situation:

```
select sender, receiver, amount, count(*)
from (select t.*,
             (select sum(t2.amount)
              from t t2
              where t2.sender = t.sender and
                    t2.receiver = t2.receiver and
                    t2.date <= t.date
             ) as cumAmount
      from t
     ) t
where cumAmount <= 200
group by sender, receiver, amount
```

Note:  in your example, the amounts are all the same for a given pair.  If they are different, then this query will list all the amounts for each pair on different rows.

Comment: Hi, actually I am using 2 tables for this, for the amount column is on the other table. How to do that? Thank you.

Comment: @andresk . . . You would need to join that information in, on each of the `from` statements.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using SQL Server 2005, you can use a `CROSS APPLY` query to get the running sum:

```
select t.sender, t.receiver,
  t.amount, c.Total
from tbl_transaction t
cross apply
(
  select count(*) total
  from tbl_transaction t1
  where t.sender = t1.sender
    and t.receiver = t1.receiver
    and t.date <= t1.date
  having sum(amount) = 200
) c;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5a01f/29)

Comment: Hi, after trying this I get what I want but other transactions with amount = 100x3, 50x3 also get in the list. Is there any way to eliminate this? I just want to get the result of people that send amount exactly 200. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Hi, the amount column is exist on other table, if I wish to use this method where should I join the two tables? Thank you.